# DJANGO: referring to id

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Here's the bit that's giving me an issue:  error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'address'

```
        bdns = Business.objects.filter(name='slow')
        addx = bdns.address
        addr = Address.objects.get(id=addx)
```

What should I do?

My model for Business:

```
class Business(models.Model): 
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A queryset is a collection, even if that collection only contains one element. When you do `Model.objects.filter()`, it returns a queryset.

If you want to return a single object, use `Model.objects.get()`.

So, for your purposes:

```
bdns = Business.objects.filter(name='slow') # returns a collection
b = dbns[0] # get the first one
the_address = b.address # the address

# or...
try:
    bdns = Business.objects.get(name='slow') # get single instance
except Business.DoesNotExist:
    bdns = None # instance didnt exist, assign None to the variable
except Business.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    bdns = None # the query returned a collection

if bdns is not None:
    the_address = bdns.address

# the_address is an instance of an Address, so no need to do the lookup with the id

print the_address.id # 7
print the_address.street # 17 John St
print the_address.city # Melbourne
```

Comment: @ellie see my edit. Once you have the Business, you can access the instance of an Address by doing `dbns.address`. No need to do another query on the Address class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    bdns = Business.objects.filter(name='slow')
```

Returns you a `QuerySet` (the collection of `Business` objects) You need to iterate to get each element with address.

```
addr = Address.objects.get(id=addx)
```

Should work